# Undefined behavior or optimization bug?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-optimization, undefined-behavior

Recently I've discovered that a code I'm working on has erroneous behavior if compiled in release mode with speed optimization. It took me a while to reduce the whole codebase to a single file such as to preserve the behavior. It becomes apparent (at least on my system) if compiled to `x64` as `C++17` with speed optimization by `VC++ 2019` `14.28.29910`. No speed optimization, `C++14`, `x86` work as expected. Also a lot of seemingly unrelated things influence the wrong outcome. That is why you can see various dummy constructs in the following example, just to preserve the error. When you compile this code, left and top for each newly emplaced element should be `20, 20` if the compiler put it as expected and garbage on a particular condition — otherwise. This condition is `std::vector`'s capacity is sufficient for emplacement without reallocation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>

void do_nothing(int) {}

struct Point { 
    float x, y; 
};

struct Size { 
    float width, height; 
};

struct Rect { 
    float left, top, right, bottom; 
};

Point origin(Rect const& rc) { 
    return { rc.left, rc.top }; 
}

Size size(Rect const& rc) { 
    return { rc.right - rc.left, rc.bottom - rc.top }; 
}

class DummyBase {
public:
    virtual void bf0() {} 
    std::vector<DummyBase*> others;
};

class Elem : public DummyBase
{
public:
    Elem(Elem& parent, Rect const& rc)
    {
        interconnect_with_parent(parent);
        _rc = rc;
    }

    Elem(Elem const& other) = delete;

    Elem& operator=(Elem const& other) = delete;

    Elem(Elem&& other) noexcept :
        DummyBase   ( std::move(other) ),
        _rc         { std::move(other._rc) }
    {       
        interconnect_with_parent(*other._parent);
        _interconnect_with_chn(std::move(other.chn));       
    }

    ~Elem() { 
        // this example is not intended for children that is not a part of their parent
        if (chn.size()) throw;
        _parent->_disconnect_child(*this); 
    }

    void interconnect_with_parent(Elem& new_parent)
    { 
        if (&new_parent != _parent) {
            _connect_parent(new_parent);
            _parent->_connect_child(*this);
        }
    }

    Rect const& rc() const {
        return _rc;
    }

    Point origin() const { 
        return ::origin(_rc); 
    }

    Size size() const { 
        return ::size(_rc); 
    }

    Elem const& parent() const {
        return *_parent;
    }

    void move(Size delta)
    { 
        _rc.left   += delta.width;
        _rc.right  += delta.width;
        _rc.top    += delta.height;
        _rc.bottom += delta.height;

        for (size_t i = 0; i < chn.size(); i++)
            chn[i]->move(delta);
    }

    void move_on_x_to(float x) {
        move(Size{ x - rc().left, 0 });
    }

    void move_on_y_to(float y) {
        move(Size{ 0, y - rc().top });
    }

    void resize(Size delta)                     
    { 
        _rc.right  += delta.width;
        _rc.bottom += delta.height;
    }

    void resize_right_to(float x) {
        resize(Size{ x - rc().right, 0 });
    }

    void resize_bottom_to(float y) {
        resize(Size{ 0, y - rc().bottom });
    }

    void print(std::string str0 = "", bool print_parent = false) const
    {
        if (not str0.empty()) 
            std::cout << str0 << ":\n";

        std::cout <<
            std::setw(col0_w) << std::left << type_name() <<
            " address: " << static_cast<const void*>(this) <<
            "\tl: " << std::setw(12) <<  _rc.left   << 
            " r: " << std::setw(12) <<  _rc.right  << 
            " t: " << std::setw(12) <<  _rc.top    << 
            " b: " << std::setw(12) <<  _rc.bottom << "\n";

        if (print_parent) {
            std::string str = " parent: ";
            std::cout << str;
            col0_w -= str.size();
            parent().print("", false);
            col0_w += str.size(); 
        }
    }

    void print_all(int sep_depth = -1, bool print_parent = false) const
    {
        auto str = type_name() + "'s tree from leaves:\n";
        std::cout << str << std::string(str.size(), '-') << "\n";
        _on_descendants(
            [print_parent](Elem& desc){ desc.print("", print_parent); },
            [sep_depth](int depth){ if (depth == 1) std::cout << "\n"; }
        );
        print("", print_parent);
    }

protected:
    void count_print_col0_w() const
    {
        col0_w = 0;
        _on_descendants([](Elem& desc){  
            size_t size = desc.type_name().size();
            if (size > col0_w) col0_w = size; 
        });
        col0_w += 10;
    }

private:
    void _interconnect_with_chn(std::vector<Elem*>&& _chn)
    { 
        chn = std::move(_chn);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < chn.size(); i++)
            chn[i]->_connect_parent(*this);
    }

    void _connect_parent(Elem& new_parent)
    {
        if (_parent) _parent->_disconnect_child(*this);  
        _parent = &new_parent; 
        main = &parent() != this ? new_parent.main : this; 
        _on_descendants([this](Elem& descendant)
        { 
            descendant.main = this->main; 
        });
    }

    void _connect_child(Elem& child)                
    { 
        if (&child != this)
            chn.push_back(&child); 
    }

    void _disconnect_child(Elem& child)             
    { 
        auto pos = std::find(chn.begin(), chn.end(), &child);
        if (pos != chn.end()) chn.erase(pos);
    }

    // act_on_desc(Elem&), act_on_depth(int)
    template<class F0, class F1 = void(int)>
    void _on_descendants(F0 act_on_desc, F1 act_on_depth = do_nothing) const
    {
        static int depth = -1;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < chn.size(); i++) {
            depth++;
            chn[i]->_on_descendants(act_on_desc, act_on_depth); 
            act_on_desc(*chn[i]), act_on_depth(depth);
            depth--;
        }
    }

    std::string type_name() const
    {
        auto type_name = std::string(typeid(*this).name());
        while (true) {
            std::string substr("class ");
            auto pos = type_name.find(substr);
            if (pos != std::string::npos) type_name.erase(pos, substr.size());
            else break;
        }
        return type_name;
    }

    Rect _rc{};
    std::vector<Elem*> chn;
    Elem* _parent{ nullptr };
    Elem* main{ nullptr };
    static size_t col0_w;
};

size_t Elem::col0_w = 50;

class PointElem : public Elem {
public:
    PointElem(Elem& parent, Point point) : 
        Elem{ parent, Rect{ point.x, point.y, point.x, point.y } } {}
};

template<class ElemT>
class DummyWrapper : public ElemT {
public:
    using ElemT::ElemT;
private:
    Elem dummy_child{ *this, ElemT::rc() };
};

// aligns, resizes and orders elements on emplace
template<class ElemT>
class ElemVec : public Elem
{
public:
    ElemVec(Elem& parent, Point origin, float right) : 
        Elem( parent, Rect{ origin.x, origin.y, right, origin.y } )
    { 
        dummy_call();
    }

    template<class...Args> 
    ElemT& emplace(Args&&...args)
    {
        auto& elem = elements.emplace_back(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        // emplaced AnotherElem's left is not what was provided
        // in Main::emplace_another_elem (that is ElemVec's left), but garbage
        // if no reallocation has occurred on emplacing
        elem.print("emplaced elem");
        adapt(elem), order_elements();
        return elem;
    }

    void adapt(Elem& elem)
    {
        if (&elem.parent() != this)
            elem.interconnect_with_parent(*this);
        elem.move_on_x_to(rc().left);
        elem.resize_right_to(rc().right);
    }

    void order_elements() 
    {
        if (not elements.empty()) 
        {
            float next_top = rc().top;
            auto iter = elements.end() - 1;
            while (true) {
                iter->move_on_y_to(next_top);
                if (iter == elements.begin()) break;
                next_top = iter->rc().bottom;
                iter--;
            }
            resize_bottom_to(iter->rc().bottom);
        }
    }

    void dummy_call() {
        if (elements.size()) 
            order_elements(), throw;
    }

    std::vector<ElemT> elements;
};

class AnotherElem_ : public Elem {
public:
    AnotherElem_(Elem& parent, Point origin, float right) : 
        Elem{ parent, Rect{ origin.x, origin.y, right, origin.y + 20 } },
        pt_elem{ std::make_unique<PointElem>(*this, this->origin()) } {}
private:
    std::unique_ptr<PointElem> pt_elem;
};

using AnotherElem = DummyWrapper<AnotherElem_>;

class Main : public Elem
{
public:
    Main(Rect const& rc) : Elem{ *this, rc } 
    {
        count_print_col0_w();
    }

    void emplace_another_elem()
    {
        size_t prev_capacity = elemvec->elements.capacity();

        float right = elemvec->rc().right;
        AnotherElem& emplaced = elemvec->emplace(*elemvec, elemvec->origin(), right);

        size_t capacity = elemvec->elements.capacity();
        if (capacity != prev_capacity) std::cout << "REALLOCATION has occurred\n";
        else std::cout << "NO REALLOCATION has occurred\n";
        emplaced.print("emplaced elem after adapting and reordering");
        std::cout << "\n";
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<ElemVec<AnotherElem>> make_elem_vec()
    {
        return std::make_unique<ElemVec<AnotherElem>>(*this, Point{ rc().left + 20, rc().top + 20 }, rc().right - 20);
    }

    std::unique_ptr<ElemVec<AnotherElem>> elemvec{ make_elem_vec() };
};

int main()
{ 
    std::cout.precision(5);

    Main m(Rect{ 0, 0, 300, 300 });
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        std::cout << "i:" << i << "\n";
        m.emplace_another_elem();
    }
    
    // just notice it has a side effect in printing order of ElemVec elements 
    // it prints in order of reconnection, but I think it probably doesn't matter for this example
    // m.print_all(2, true);

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

I've generated an assembly listing. And it looks like on a branch with no reallocation the stack memory where the compiler put the origin

```
movsd QWORD PTR $T4[rsp], xmm1
```

becomes overwritten

```
mov QWORD PTR $T18[rsp], rbx
```

probably with `_Mylast` pointer of `std::vector` before a call to `AnotherElem` constructor occurs. `$T4`, `$T4`, `$T18` is the same offset.

```
_TEXT   SEGMENT
$T32 = 48
$T18 = 48
$T3 = 48
$T4 = 48
$T24 = 56
$T35 = 56
$T22 = 88
$T33 = 88
right$ = 88
__$ArrayPad$ = 96
this$ = 144

?emplace_another_elem@Main@@QEAAXXZ PROC        ; Main::emplace_another_elem, COMDAT

; 
; ... omission ...
; 

; 313  :  float right = elemvec->rc().right;

    movss   xmm3, DWORD PTR [rdi+40]
    movss   DWORD PTR right$[rsp], xmm3

; 24   :  return { rc.left, rc.top }; 

    movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR [rdi+36]

; 77   :  return ::origin(_rc); 

    movss   xmm1, DWORD PTR [rdi+32]
    unpcklps xmm1, xmm0
    movsd   QWORD PTR $T4[rsp], xmm1

; 711  :  if (_Mylast != _My_data._Myend) {

    mov rbx, QWORD PTR [rdi+96]
    cmp rbx, QWORD PTR [rdi+104]
    je  SHORT $LN16@emplace_an

; 695  :  static void construct(_Alloc&, _Objty* const _Ptr, _Types&&... _Args) {

    mov QWORD PTR $T18[rsp], rbx
    mov rax, QWORD PTR $T3[rsp]
    mov QWORD PTR $T22[rsp], rax
    mov r8, rax
    mov rdx, rdi
    mov rcx, rbx
    call    ??0AnotherElem_@@QEAA@AEAVElem@@UPoint@@M@Z ; AnotherElem_::AnotherElem_
    npad    1
    lea rax, OFFSET FLAT:??_7?$DummyWrapper@VAnotherElem_@@@@6B@
    mov QWORD PTR [rbx], rax
    lea rcx, QWORD PTR [rbx+96]
    lea r8, QWORD PTR [rbx+32]
    mov rdx, rbx
    call    ??0Elem@@QEAA@AEAV0@AEBURect@@@Z    ; Elem::Elem
    npad    1
```

Why does the compiler put it there if it shortly becomes overwritten anyway. Doesn't seem like optimization to me. Also it would be nice if you pointed out possible causes of UB in the code.

*Edit:* fixed some errors which don't emerge in VS2019

Comment: You have a lot of code posted, and it is not immediately clear where the error is. Can you minimize it further? However, I am pretty sure the bug is on your side.

Comment: Also, random observation: `Elem(Elem&& other) noexcept : DummyBase   ( std::move(other) ),_rc{ std::move(other._rc) }` is using object after it was moved from. Might not be problematic in your code, but overall smells fishy.

Comment: @SergeyA, further minimization will most likely eliminate the error. At this point it's hard to make any change while preserving it.

Comment: Your code can not be compiled `as-is`. See https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/4K5ojjYWz I think, at the bare minimum you should start with code which is warning (and errors) free. After that, try running it through static analyzer / valgrind and see if something interesting pops up.

Comment: In the `elem` destructor `throw;` looks out of place. Usually you only see this inside a catch block where it rethrows the current exception. Everywhere else you typically want to throw something.

Comment: `(std::stringstream() << static_cast<const void*>(this)).str()` doesn't look right either. `<<` should return an `ostream`, and shouldn't have a `str` method.

Comment: Without analyzing all the code, I would be looking for dangling references when vectors resize, or destruction via the wrong type (base class does not have a virtual destructor)